# How can I increase the code coverage when many classes have already reached the 75% of code coverage mark?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

How should I cover the code when most of the classes have covered the code greater than 75%?

[image]

Comment: What I learn is not all classes have reached 75% yet! Try the one which is below 75% to extend overall furthermore of 74%. 
I literally calculated the average of these percentages and it was nearby the one it has stated. That means to cross the required mark of 75%, you need to increase the coverage a little more for classes which have below 75%. Rest assured, I understand many of the classes have already crossed 80% of code coverage.

Comment: One suggestion: Try not to stick  to 75%, it may fail/decrease while deployment. As a good practice try to cover 80-85% code coverage so that you can be sure that it won't break while deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how to increase the overall code coverage of your org.
Try to increase the code coverage for the classes bellow 75% individually so that overall code coverage goes above 75%.

Specially increase the code coverage for Export Document Class

Answer (score 0):

Or you may increase the code coverage of longest class.(not eligible but may works)

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer console run your all test classes now see indivisual classes code coverage , in those who has less code coverage , try to increase code cover for those particular classes, try to increase code coverage for FLS_Security class and ExportDocument Class